# JavaBehaviour NotificationFrequency

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I use alfresco 4.2f community edition, and in the official documentation I don't understand for JavaBehaviour NotificationFrequency what is the difference among:

```
NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT 
NotificationFrequency.FIRST_EVENT
NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT
```

In particular between the first and the third.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using NotificationFrequency you can decide when the behavior should be invoked by specifying
the appropriate NotificationFrequency.

1. NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT
   *This will be called every time when event is occurred.*

   NotificationFrequency.FIRST_EVENT 
   *This will be called only once.*

   NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT 
   *This will be called when transaction is committed.*

You will get more idea when you read content of below link.Also read the comment of Axel Faust.

http://alfresco.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2014/10/14/specialize-type-upon-content-creation-within-behaviour-can-result-in-invalid-version-history/